# Use function data as html id Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, ajax

I want to use the function data as id, tried alot but nothing worked, how should i do it here is my code, thanks in advance

```
function SLIDE_HIDE(SLIDEID)
{
    $("#($SLIDEID).val()").prop('value', 'hide');
}
```

Comment: So `SLIDEID` has the id of the element you want?

Answer (score 1):

```
function SLIDE_HIDE(slideId)
{
    $("#" + $(slideId).val()).prop('value', 'hide');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate:

```
$("#" + SLIDEID)
```

Which means that if the `SLIDEID` argument is, say, the string `"test"` then it will be like saying `$("#test")`.

You were trying to select an element with an id equal to all of the text in the string after `#`, i.e., an element with `id="($SLIDEID).val()"`.

If you are trying to hide the element that has the id in the `SLIDEID` argument then do this:

```
$("#" + SLIDEID).hide();
```

If you want to change that element's value then (assuming it is a form element like an input):

```
$("#" + SLIDEID).val('hide');
```

The code you showed sort of looks like you're trying to retrieve the value from an element with the id specified in `SLIDEID` and then use that value as the id to look up another element and set that other element's value to the string `'hide'`. That doesn't really make sense to me, but if it's what you want to do:

```
$("#" + $("#" + SLIDEID).val()).prop('value', 'hide');
```

Comment: thanks it worked! what i want to do now is to toggle the textvalue of the button, this is the working code sir 
function SLIDE_HIDE(SLIDEID)
{
  $("#"+SLIDEID).prop('value', 'HIDE');
}